# Resolve conflicting jquery plugins: quicksand and lavalamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I have a problem with [jQuery Quicksand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) and [jQuery Lavalamp](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/23/lavalamp-for-jquery-lovers/) plugins.

It seems they conflict and don't work together. I wonder why and how can I solve this?
I'm using jQuery 1.4.2

Comment: Please post error messages and other problems you encounter by pressing the 'edit' link under your question (don't post an answer with more information).

Comment: Could you please share the code on how you are trying to use them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with jQuery Easing plugin. It was included 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

A  jQuery Ex is like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.dropdown-horizontal ul li:has(ul)").addClass("dir");
    });

    $(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:      'scrollDown',
    timeout:  5000,
    pause:   1,
    speedIn:  2000,
    speedOut: 500,
    easeIn:  'bounceout',
    easeOut: 'backin',
    delay:   -2000
    });
    });
    </script>
```

This code running perfect, if there are no other jQuery code. But it will be got an  error if you has another jQuery code. So to handle this problem, you need to has a unique variable. I mean mostly $ (variables) is the default code of jQuery, so we must to create unique variable

This is an example of the code after I make unique variables,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $jx = jQuery.noConflict();

$jx(document).ready(function() {
$jx("ul.dropdown-horizontal ul li:has(ul)").addClass("dir");
});

$jx(function() {
$jx('#slideshow').cycle({
fx:      'scrollDown',
timeout:  5000,
pause:   1,
speedIn:  2000,
speedOut: 500,
easeIn:  'bounceout',
easeOut: 'backin',
delay:   -2000
});
});
</script>
```

When you check the second code, you will found a unique variable $jx as a new variable and replace default $.

Refer : http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries